# is it possible to create "slide" transition when div changes position? (flexbox, js)

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I'm playing around with flexbox and JS and I was wondering if it is possible to make a transition on moving div after sibling div "disappeared"?

So parent has two child nodes in a row ("car" as a first-child and "Cable" as a last-child), each have own data-value (car and Cable), if we search by "ca" it will be showing both divs but if we add "b" ("cab") it will show just the last-child and first-child will disappear, and I'm talking about this "disappear" moment when first-child is going "display: none;" and I want to make nice div slide from last-child to first-child position.

```js
const childNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".child");

search.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  for(const childNode of childNodes){
    const dataValue = childNode.getAttribute("data-value").toLowerCase();
    
    if(!dataValue.includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
        childNode.classList.add("searchHidden");
    } else {
        childNode.classList.remove("searchHidden");
    }
}});
```

```css
    body {
      background: lightblue;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .parent {
         margin-top: 3rem;
         display: flex;
         column-gap: 1rem;
         height: 70vh;
         padding: 0 0.5rem;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
         align-content: flex-start;
    }

    .child {
         flex-basis: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
         height: 10rem; // 160px
         border: 0.05rem solid #f4f4f4;
         background-color: green;
         margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    
    .searchHidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Search:</span>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" data-value="car"></div>
  <div class="child" data-value="Cable"></div>
</div>
```

Could someone point me a direction, where to look and read or any idea that would help me?
I would be grateful, sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late! If I understood you correctly, you want an animation which brings the blocks/boxes which contain the search parameter to the first places; One way you could achieve this is by using `width` and `transition`, while setting the `display` to `block` (just inside the `searchHidden` class), and replacing the `flex-basis` with `width`, which will allow the falsey boxes to "collapse" into a single pixel before having their `display` set to `none`.
Here is the code snippet:
PS: please not I did not pick the best transition timings. If you change this, and I recommend you do, you must also change the `setTimeout(function(){...},550)` function to `setTimeout(function(){...},x)`, where x is the timing of the `transition` of the `.child` class, in milliseconds.

```js
const childNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
const search = document.getElementById("search");

search.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  for(const childNode of childNodes){
    const dataValue = childNode.getAttribute("data-value").toLowerCase();

    if(!dataValue.includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) && search.value){
        setTimeout(function() {
            childNode.classList.add("searchHidden");
        },50)
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(!dataValue.includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) && search.value) {
                childNode.style.display = "none";
            }
        },550);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){childNode.classList.remove("searchHidden");},100)
        childNode.style.display = "block";

    }

}

});
```

```css
      body {
        background: #d7d7d7;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      .parent {
           margin-top: 3rem;
           display: flex;
           column-gap: 1rem;
           height: 70vh;
           padding: 0 0.5rem;
           flex-wrap: wrap;
           align-content: flex-start;
      }

      .child {
           transition: all 550ms ease-out;
           width: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
           height: 10rem; // 160px
           border: 0.05rem solid #f4f4f4;
           background-color: #fff;
           margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }

      .searchHidden {
        transform: scale(0);
        width: 0px;
        color: transparent;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <span>Search:</span>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" data-value="car">Car</div>
  <div class="child" data-value="Cable">Cable</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost, I'm looking for something like this https://streamable.com/a2u42f but good job and ty for trying.

Comment: @Stranger, No problem :)

Comment: @Stranger, or anyone interested: I have now improved the animation, and it looks better!